# iAP Auto-renewable subscription on restore all finished transactions are back

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I am on iOS 15

I have implemented iAP purchase with auto-renewable subscription, on first purchase all is good, and I finish the transaction once I get reply back from the backend server.
The issue is when clicking on restore, all old transactions are back, i.e:

```
    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    
    for transaction in transactions {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
        case .purchased:
            completePurchaseTransaction(transaction)
        case .restored:
            completeRestoreTransactions(transaction)
        case .failed:
            failedTransaction(transaction)
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is:

1. Trying to send every transaction to the backend server, it results with no restore available since they were consumed, and multiple popups, bad UI experience.
2. The iTunes Store becomes unresponsive later on when I try to fetch available products or buy new consumable product.
3. It puts so much load on the backend server due to a lot of transactions to be processed.

I have tried to finish the transactions in the following delegate:

```
    public func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
    for transaction in queue.transactions
    {
        SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
    }
}
```

Another issue I have noticed is that, after I do a restore and get error that no subscription is found, I try to purchase now an auto-renewable subscription, the first delegate shows a new transaction but when validating the receipt with the backend, the receipt doesn't contain the new subscription. Thus I cannot purchase a new subscription

---

I tried to send only unique transactions, so I filtered the array to get only unique objects with unique product Identifier. Which resulted in only getting one transaction out of 50.
I sent this to the server and it worked well, but the issue is when I try now to purchase the auto-renewable subscription, it doesn't add a new transaction in the receipt and I am back to the old issue where I can't purchase a new subscription

Any ideas of how to deal with auto-renewable subscriptions, purchase, restore, display alerts for different phases, etc...

Comment: "I get reply back from the backend server"  A reply?  What kind of reply are you referring to?  When and how do you get one?

Comment: I mean when validating the receipt at my backend then it replies back to the app that the purchase is valid or not.